# Magento - Paypal Express 404 Error

Tags: magento, paypal

I have added paypal pro (uk) express to my Magento shopping cart.  The paypal button now appears below the checkout button in the shopping cart.

The problem is when I click the paypal button I get a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by following post 5 here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=8528

I needed to delete the paypal files in the default folder.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you added a payment method for the checkout process or a custom paypal checkout.
Activate the debug mode and the error logging in system->configuration->developer. Having a more verbose error message will point you to a more clear error.

404 is page not found error, so wherever the paypal module is pointing the page is missiong. This could happen as a result of malconfiguration or API change or other issues.

Comment: I enabled the api debug and tried again.  Got the error and then checked the paypal_api_debug table in the db but it was empty.  I also turned the debugger and logs on.  I checked the exception log in the var/log folder but nothing in there either.

Comment: I just tried choosing paypal express from the checkout page. Was going ok until paypal tried returning to http://mysite/paypal/express/review/ and I just got a blank page.  Checked my plesk error log and found this:

[Wed Mar 17 22:47:10 2010] [error] [client 95.145.166.175] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuote() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php on line 142, referer: https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=-I3FWlf802TzN6eWIjQBCDfIzwoWLqz-mgIt_9LZODcT1VVofGd5aE9BqVO&

Comment: looks like a visualization issue. the paypal.express.review (Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Review) block is not instantiated properly. you should address a paypal developer forum: http://paypaldev.org/ or send a bug report to paypal